# I am not receiving Facebook Comments notifications

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have installed Facebook Comments for my Wordpress blog and everythings is working fine except for the fact that I'm not receiving notifications on facebook.com

1) I'm setupped as a Moderator of the apps

2) Meta properties :  fb:app_id and fb:admins are set correctly.

3) Comments are getting in the moderation area so they are definitively there.

Is there anything else to checkout?

I have even try to create the whole process again with a new apps to see if I would have corrupted my apps in some way but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

From [**Facebook Comments Box Docs**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

> How do I know when someone comments on my site?
>
> You can subscribe to the 'comment.create' and 'comment.remove' events
>   through [FB.Event.subscribe.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)

You can use `comment.create` to do that, But it's impossible to get notified on Facebook